# Write mass, customized letter

Tags: python

how do I get it so that 3 messages are generated, each with the corresponding name and grade

```
names = ['Arthur', 'Brian', 'Clare']
grades = [71, 82, 93]

message = "{}, your grade is {}.".format(names, grades)

for name, grade in zip(names, grades):
    print(message.format(name, grade))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After applying `format` the string no longer the special bracket to format something else

```
message = "{}, your grade is {}.".format(names, grades)
print(message)  # ['Arthur', 'Brian', 'Clare'], your grade is [71, 82, 93].
```

---

Keep the string containing the bracket for formatting

```
message = "{}, your grade is {}."
for name, grade in zip(names, grades):
    print(message.format(name, grade))
```